# Open/save PDF located in server folder

Tags: php, pdf, save

I want to give to the users of a PHP intranet the possibility to open/save PDF files, which are located in a folder on the Apache server. The PDFs have company private information, so I don't want to put them in a web folder.

```
echo '<form name="openpdf" method="POST" action="downloadPDF.php">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="pdf">';
echo'</form>';

<tr>
<td> PDFFile1 </td>
<td><a href=javascript:void(null); onclick='document.openpdf.pdf.value="c:\pdfs\example.pdf";document.openpdf.submit(); return false;'><IMG src="img/pdf.jpg"></a></td></tr>
```

downloadPDF.php:

```
<?
$pdf=$_POST["pdf"];
if (file_exists($pdf)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');   
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($pdf));   
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');     
    header('Expires: 0');    
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');   
    header('Pragma: public');   
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($pdf));     
    ob_clean();     
    flush();     
    readfile($pdf);     
    exit; 
} 
?>
```

The problem is when the user open/save a file, the path is pointing for that folder but in the client PC and not at the server.

Comment: The general process would be download, edit and put it back.. But what do you want exactly?

Comment: open pdf files that are stored in a folder on the apache server.

Comment: Presumably once this is served over the intranet, the copy "in the client PC" is in a temp folder, saved by the browser. This is normal - if you want to be able to save to the centralised copy, you probably need a network file server instead.

Comment: Btw, it is unusual for the client to specify the full path of a file on the server. At present, this script permits any of your intranet users from obtaining any file on the server, which is probably not very secure!

Answer (score 1):

If you process the PDFs internally on the server from PHP, you should omit the `file:///` from the URL.

So it should be

```
$pdf="c:/pdfs/example.pdf";
```

Comment: Same result! Points to the client c:/pdfs/example.pdf

Comment: @MikeDias What do you mean by "points" ?? On the client side, the browser receives the PDF, where is the URL being showed here?

Comment: If I create that folder in the client pc and copy the example.pdf, then in my page the open/save works because php is looking for the pdf in the client c:\pdfs\   How can i change the code to make sure that the source path is on the server folder and not in the client? Thanks!

Comment: What?! `Content-disposition...` header will make the browser "download" the PDF file from server's `c:\path\path`. Where is the client's role here? I am sorry, but I do not understand. Please update your question with proper description.

Answer (score 0):

The server does not know the client PC, so `readfile` does not work here.

You might want to try with a redirect, but I must admit I have no clue if browsers allow that for security reasons (you're switching protocols with the redirect).

Answer (score 0):

What at the moment you are doing is that

1. Javascript is putting a value of `c:\pdfs\example.pdf` in the pdf field of your form on click and submitting it to downloadpdf.php.
2. On server, Downloadpdf.php is assigning $_POST["pdf"] value to $pdf.
3. If file $pdf exists, it is simply proceeding to offer user to download this file.

Now, this **may** work where server & client is same computer(specifically on a PC, because of `C:` drive); i.e. like on Local XAMPP. But on real world, where user and server will be on totally different computers, the `if (file_exists($pdf))` is always going to fail(unless On server's `C:` actually there is a file `exaple.pdf` in folder `pdfs`)
In real world, step 3 will fail, because $pdf = `c:\pdfs\example.pdf` and server will look into *its own* `C:` drive (if it is a windows server).
You should

1 Try to upload file with an HTML File Upload Box.
2 Get/fetch it on server using $_FILES and do processing
3. Send required headers for downloading.

For further information, please see [HTML Form File Upload (Google)](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=html+form+file+upload) &  [$_FILES (PHP.Net)](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)